# Why aren't characters treated as integers?

Tags: python

It's always bugged me that typing out the raw alphabet  (`alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`) is shorter than the way I would think to use:

```
alphabet = list(chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1))
```

Of course, you could also just `from string import ascii_lowercase`, but that's irrelevant to the question. Why are characters not valid inputs to a `range` function? The following code works, proving that `range` can use any value with the `__index__` function implemented:

```
class Doubler(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value * 2

    def __int__(self):
        return self.value
    __index__ = __int__

for i in range(Doubler(5), Doubler(10)):
    print(i)
```

[10, 20) is printed line by line, meaning it clearly works. So why don't characters return their `ord` from the `__index__` function? Obviously this wouldn't work with strings longer than length 1, but neither does `ord`. Is there some reason I'm missing here? We could have `range('a', 'z' + 1)`, which is much clearer IMO.

Comment: How do you *know*  the characters `a` through `z` are represented by consecutive binary values in the character set in use?

Comment: So then should `'a' + 'b' == 198`? Seems like the functionality you're looking for would be better implemented into a custom `range()` function rather than completely change the way strings work.

Comment: @AndrewHenle As far as I was aware, Python strings were unicode by default. Even if they're not consecutive, that isn't incorrect. I could get a range from `_` to `%` if I wished.

Comment: @Jkdc `'a' + 'b'` would still equal `"ab"`, as `__index__` is not meant to be used for mathematics, it is an index.

Comment: *"Obviously this wouldn't work with strings longer than length 1"* – So strings should treat themselves as numbers as long as they're 1 character long, otherwise they shouldn't? Just saying that sounds like such a messy special case that I'm surely glad they don't. Python does very little implicit type conversions, most need to be explicit. I think that's a sensible design, and what you're asking for doesn't sound like it's worth breaking that.

Comment: For what it's worth, in Perl you can do this; `++'zz'` is `'aaa'`. I don't think Python particularly needs this behavior; a clean, predictable, well-defined behavior is much preferrable, and the workaround is basically a one-liner if you ever really need this functionality.

Comment: Admittedly, there are some good points here. Defining my own `char_range` generator for characters seems just as clean.

Answer (score 0):

Because 'a' and 'z' are strings, why they should use ord of first symbol as `__index__`? Also take a note that abstract string can be empty.

Comment: `ord` takes a string as well. Any string not of length 1 will throw an error, which I addressed in the question. `__index__` should throw an error in the same circumstances.